# Java KeyListener - How to detect if any key is pressed?

Tags: java, key, keyevent, any, pressed

I've added a KeyListener to a TextArea and wish to check if *any* key is pressed down.
I have the following but it's too clumsy to check for all the letters and numbers:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A || e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_B || 
e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C ||e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D etc...){  

    }   
}
```

Comment: Beware, it's possible for text components to consume mouse events, which makes it unreliable, typically you would use a DocumentListener to be notified when the text component is changed or DocumentFilter if you want to filter what is been entered

Comment: Ah thanks. I've never used a DocumentListener before, I'll probably use that instead..

Comment: I second @MadProgrammer's recommendation. It is dangerous to use KeyListeners on text components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't need any if statements. The `keyPressed` method is fired whenever a key is pressed, so you're automatically thrown into the method.

Comment: i believe he has some action to be performed on some specific keys press event.

Comment: No, actually the action is not specific to the key. Thank you very much, Embattled Swag.

Comment: @EfeEsenwa No problem. If my answer helped, you should accept it, so other people can see it. You do that by clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Better not to recommend use of KeyListeners on a JTextArea or any text component. This is dangerous advise you're giving.

Comment: This may not work reliably on all platforms or even under different versions of the JVM - just saying...

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `KeyEvent.getKeyChar() or KeyEvent.getKeyCode()` method which will returns character value/code of key pressed.

For alphanumericals A-Z,a-z,0-9;

```
int key= KeyEvent.getKeyCode();

if((((key>=65)&&(key<=90))||((key>=97)&&(key<=122))||((key>=48)&&(key<=57)))
{
//Do action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of respective key events and check if the list contains those events.

```
List keyEvents = new ArrayList<KeyEvent>();
keyEvents.add(KeyEvent.VK_A);
keyEvents.add(KeyEvent.VK_B);
keyEvents.add(KeyEvent.VK_C);
keyEvents.add(KeyEvent.VK_D);

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
if(keyEvents.contains(e.getKeyCode())){  

    }   
}
```